# Primitive divisors of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, distribution-of-primes

The well known Fibonacci sequence $F_{0} = 0, F_{1} = 1$ and, by recurrence law, $F_{n+1}:=F_{n} +F_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 1$,  has the following property (proved by Carmichael  in 1913):

*With the exception of $F_{1} = F_{2} = 1, F_{6} = 8$ and $F_{12} = 144$  every Fibonacci number $F_{n}$ has a prime factor that is not a factor of any smaller Fibonacci number.*

Such a prime factor is called a **Primitive Divisor of $F_{n}$**.

Anybody knows if in the decomposition in prime factors of $F_{n}$, with $n\not\in \{1,2,6,12\}$ can appear a power greater than $1$ of some primitive divisor of $F_{n}$? That is, if $p$ is some primitive divisor of $F_{n}$, then $p^k$  does not divide $F_{n}$ for $k > 1$?

Many thanks in advanced for your comments.

Comment: I doubt much is provable.  I suggest starting with a fairly deep search.

Comment: An efficient way to search for such a prime is to determine , for a given prime $p$ , the smallest positive integer $k$ with $p\mid fib(k)$. If we even have $p^2\mid fib(k)$ , we have found an example. There is no such example upto $p=10^4$. Hence such a prime factor must exceed $10^4$.

Comment: Extended to $p=132\ 000$ without finding an example. However, heuristically , there should be infinite many such cases considering that the chance of a success is about $1/p$ and the sum over the reciprocals of the primes diverges (but extremely slow indeed)

Comment: Not going to happen, see [Pisano periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period).

Comment: Proof of Carmichael's theorem that you are willing to strengthen?

Comment: @IvanNeretin If you can prove that there cannot be such a prime factor , please post it.

Comment: @Peter Thought I can, but it turns out that I was wrong. Now the question seems to be hinged on the existence of the so-called [Wall–Sun–Sun primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall%E2%80%93Sun%E2%80%93Sun_prime), which itself is an open question.

Comment: @IvanNeretin This would however also be interesting since those primes have been searched upto  a quite high limit. If you have any useful relations , you can post them as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an answer, but here are some consolatory news: **nobody has**.

The question is hinged on the existence of the so-called [Wall–Sun–Sun primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall%E2%80%93Sun%E2%80%93Sun_prime), which itself is an open question. See, it says right there, under "Equivalent definitions":

> ...a Wall–Sun–Sun prime can be equivalently defined as a prime $p$ such
> that $p^2$ divides $F_{\alpha (p)}$.

(They use some savage terminology in which the relation *"$p$ is a primitive divisor of $F_n$"* must be restated as *"$n$ is the rank of apparition modulo $p$"*, or "$n=\alpha(p)$". With that in mind, the message is as clear as the day.)

The search of Wall–Sun–Sun primes up to $2^{64}$ brought no results.

So it goes.